# Jsoup fetches wrong results

Tags: java, jsoup

Working with Jsoup. The URL works well on the browser. But it fetches wrong result on the server. I set the maxBodySize "0" as well. But it still only gets first few tags. Moreover the data is even different from the browser one. Can you guys give me a hand?

```
String queryUrl = "http://www.juso.go.kr/addrlink/addrLinkApi.do?confmKey=U01TX0FVVEgyMDE3MDYyODE0MTYyMzIyMTcw&currentPage=1&countPerPage=20&keyword=연남동";

Document document = Jsoup.connect(queryUrl).maxBodySize(0).get();
```

Comment: No it doesn't. The site does not require to log in or any authentication but only confirmation key which I have already got. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried clearing all cookies and caches in your browser and trying it again? Try getting your browser as close as possible to the server's state.

Comment: I don't think the problem has something to do with the browser.

Comment: It fetches the right data on the browser in which "<totalCount>" says 20..something and follows data tags. But on the server Document gets <totalCount> as 0 and no error but it has no data following.

Comment: I have cleaned all the cookies and cache, but still has the same issue.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry. You may have to resort to debugging, browser developer tools Net view, and that sort of thing. If you learn anything useful, update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that this endpoint returns paginated data? Your URL asks for 20 entries from the first page. I assume that the order of these entries is not specified so you can get different data each time you call this endpoint - check if there is a URL parameter that can determine specific sort order.

Anyway to read all 2037 entries you have to do it sequentially. Examine following code:

```
final String baseUrl = "http://www.juso.go.kr/addrlink/addrLinkApi.do";
final String key = "U01TX0FVVEgyMDE3MDYyODE0MTYyMzIyMTcw";
final String keyword = "연남동";
final int perPage = 100;
int currentPage = 1;

while (true) {
    System.out.println("Downloading data from page " + currentPage);
    final String url = String.format("%s?confmKey=%s&currentPage=%d&countPerPage=%d&keyword=%s", baseUrl, key, currentPage, perPage, keyword);

    final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).maxBodySize(0).get();

    final Elements jusos = document.getElementsByTag("juso");
    System.out.println("Found " + jusos.size() + " juso entries");

    if (jusos.size() == 0) {
    break;
    }

    currentPage += 1;
}
```

In this case we are asking for 100 entries per page (that's the maximum number this endpoint supports) and we call it 21 times, as long as calling for a specific page return any `<juso>` element. Hope it helps solving your problem.